# Built in error type that cannot be handled and just contains a message?

Tags: rust

Is there a built in error type that just prints a message, but cannot do anything else? I don't need to be able to know what the error is, I just want to print it to a log file. It will effectively be a silent panic, since the error is one severity down from 'unrecoverable'.

The error signifies that a bug has occurred, but since it will run on a persistent server, I just need to interrupt the task that's running, rather than the whole process. The rest of the code can recover from this, but not the task.

I would like to do the following:

```rust
use ...::SomeError;

fn some_operation() -> Result<i32, impl Error> {
  let value: Option<i32> = /*some fallible operation that will work if there's no bug*/;
  value.ok_or_else(|| SomeError::new("Something just happened that probably shouldn't have".to_string()))
}
```

I know I can define a custom error type to do this, but I'd like to use a builtin if there's one defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.68.0/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#2260-2300) and [`&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.68.0/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#2326-2346) implement `Into<Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>>`, so you can just use that directly:

```rust
fn some_operation() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    let value: Option<i32> = /*some fallible operation that will work if there's no bug*/;
    Ok(value.ok_or("Something just happened that probably shouldn't have")?)
}
```